# String matching in Peewee (SQL)

Tags: sql, peewee

I am trying to query in Peewee with results that should have a specific substring in them.

For instance, if I want only activities with "Physics" in the name:

```
schedule = Session.select().join(Activity).where(Activity.name % "%Physics%").join(Course).join(StuCouRel).join(Student).where(Student.id == current_user.id)
```

The above example doesn't give any errors, but doesn't work correctly.

In python, I would just do `if "Physics" in Activity.name`, so I'm looking for an equivalent which I can use in a query.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Quick answer:

just use `Activity.name.contains('Physics')`

---

Depending on the database backend you're using you'll want to pick the right "wildcard".  Postgresql and MySQL use "%", but for Sqlite if you're performing a `LIKE` query you will actually want to use "*" (although for ILIKE it is "%", confusing).

I'm going to guess you're using SQLite since the above query is failing, so to recap, with SQLite if you want case-sensitive partial-string matching: `Activity.name % "*Physics*"`, and for case-insensitive: `Activity.name ** "%Physics%"`.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like

Comment: Thanks. It's very confusing indeed. I was using SQLite for development, but I'll most likely switch to PostgreSQL for production, so that means that I would have to change it?

Comment: Yeah, I may need to add an attribute like ``db.wildcard`` so your code will be portable, though of course you can add that to your own code as well.

Comment: You can use ``Activity.name.contains('Physics')`` and it should do the right thing!

Answer (score 30):

You could also use [these](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#query-operators) query methods: `.contains(substring)`, `.startswith(prefix)`, `.endswith(suffix)`.

For example, your where clause could be:

```
.where(Activity.name.contains("Physics"))
```

I believe this is case-insensitive and behaves the same as  `LIKE '%Physics%'`.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: This is a simpler and better solution. Please mark it as the Accepted answer.

Comment: This works in the case-insensitive scenario, how about for the case-sensitive scenario?